# sony smartwatch sw2 launcher app

Tags: launcher, sony, sony-smartwatch

I'm working on a Control Extension for Sony SmartWatch 2 that needs to become a launcher app when user wakes up the sw2 device.

My app works like a location monitor app. User can monitor the gps location where he is.
And sw2 always goes to sleep after 10 secs. user has to "find" and "restart" the same app to keep monitor location. It is boring.

1. I know that it is impossible to set my app to a watchface.
2. I try to use Control.Intents.SCREEN_STATE_ON, but battery only support 2~3 hours.

My question is..

Is it possible to set my app the launcher app when user wakes up the sw2?
User still can use "home" button or "prev" button to go to home screen.

Comment: What do you mean by launcher app?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by what you mean by "launcher app" as well.

Also, when the watch goes to sleep, the current extension should pause and then resume when you wake the SW2 up using the power button.  So the user doesn't have to find and restart it again.  If your app is exiting sounds like you must not be handing something correctly.

Comment: Yes I found the bug in my app. Thank you.